# Python pandas duplicate rows based on number and increment

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe on which I wanna duplicate rows based on the min and max values (duplication number for every row = `max`-`min`). And on top, I want to create a column for which every row increments based on these same min and max.

For instance, if min = 3 and max = 6, i want the row to appear 4 times (duplicate it 3 times), and every duplication should have the value column worth from 3 to 6 and increment for every duplication.

Example input:

| ID | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product ABC | 3 | 6 |
| Product XXXX | 8 | 10 |

Desired output:

| ID | min | max | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product ABC | 3 | 6 | 3 |
| Product ABC | 3 | 6 | 4 |
| Product ABC | 3 | 6 | 5 |
| Product ABC | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| Product XXXX | 8 | 10 | 8 |
| Product XXXX | 8 | 10 | 9 |
| Product XXXX | 8 | 10 | 10 |

Answer (score 1):

With making ranges from `min` to `max` and exploding them (with [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)):

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['min'], x['max'] + 1), axis=1)
df = df.explode('value', ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
              ID  min  max value
0   Product ABC     3    6     3
1   Product ABC     3    6     4
2   Product ABC     3    6     5
3   Product ABC     3    6     6
4  Product XXXX     8   10     8
5  Product XXXX     8   10     9
6  Product XXXX     8   10    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by difference of columns with add `1`, repeat by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last add counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `min` column:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['max'].sub(df['min']) + 1)]
        
df1['value'] = df1['min'].add(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
print (df1)
             ID  min  max  value
0   Product ABC    3    6      3
0   Product ABC    3    6      4
0   Product ABC    3    6      5
0   Product ABC    3    6      6
1  Product XXXX    8   10      8
1  Product XXXX    8   10      9
1  Product XXXX    8   10     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the rows with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), then [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the new column with help of [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
rep = df['max'].sub(df['min']).add(1)

out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(rep)]
         .assign(value=lambda d: d.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(d['min']))
      )
```

Output:

```
             ID  min  max  value
0   Product ABC    3    6      3
0   Product ABC    3    6      4
0   Product ABC    3    6      5
0   Product ABC    3    6      6
1  Product XXXX    8   10      8
1  Product XXXX    8   10      9
1  Product XXXX    8   10     10
```

Intermediates:

```
             ID  min  max  value  rep  cumcount
0   Product ABC    3    6      3    4         0
0   Product ABC    3    6      4    4         1
0   Product ABC    3    6      5    4         2
0   Product ABC    3    6      6    4         3
1  Product XXXX    8   10      8    3         0
1  Product XXXX    8   10      9    3         1
1  Product XXXX    8   10     10    3         2
```